# Is there any way to control height of text with in rectangle vertex

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

Is there any way to control height of text within rectangle vertex of mxGraph ?

I Just want to hide extra text from bottom of rectangle.

See below screenshot to see what is happening.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `overflow=hidden` in style of rectangle vertex solved my problem.

Now rectangle is showing as below.

[image]